# Search button, datatype missmatch

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, types

i am trying to do a search button which can search for both surname and user id from just one search bar,

```
 SELECT user_id, Title, FirstName, Surname, Address, PostCode, PhoneNumber 
 from [User] 
 WHERE (Not (user_id)=100003)
 and (user_id= '$ID' or Surname ='ID')
 order by user_id
```

this issue is, user_id is and int and surname is nvarchard datatype, so is i search for user id i get the output, but when i search for surname i get the error - 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'nes' to data type int

any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is 'nes' isn't a valid number.  SQL Server doesn't know how to look for this value in an integer column.

You can work around this by casting your INT field into a nVarChar.  Here's an [example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/401593/casting-int-to-nvarchar):

```
-- What we are searching for.
DECLARE @SearchFor    NVARCHAR(255) = '1';

-- Use a CTE to create some sample records to search.
WITH SampleData AS
(
    /* Create some sample records.
        */
    SELECT
        r.[User_Id],
        r.Name
    FROM
        (
            VALUES
                (1, 'Tom'),
                (2, 'Dick'),
                (3, 'Harry')
        ) AS r([User_Id], Name)
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SampleData
WHERE
    @SearchFor IN (CAST([User_id] AS NVARCHAR(255)), Name)
;
```

Comment: Should have added; this works by converting 1, 2 and 3 into '1', '2' and '3'.  Although they look like numbers they aren't.  They are now text, which can be compared to other text values, like 'nes'.